# PHP Define a Resource URL

Tags: php, variables, session, iis, global

We run an IIS server that hosts multiple internal websites. Recently we have updated a lot of our tools and noticed that we have some common URLs that point to a core intranet site. We had to manually update those links when it changed.

What I would like to do is create some type of "Config" variable that can hold these common resource URL's in which we can use them in any of our websites at any time.

From what I have read, some people suggest `Define` but that seems to only be in the scope of the project you are working on.

I guess my question is - What is the best way to define some common URL's that can be used in multiple sites? I'd prefer not to have to do an include file in all of them if possible so something on a variable / session level would be best.

Thoughts on a good solution?

Comment: @SSB: are you comfortable setting/getting environment variables as a solution?

Comment: Where would they have to be defined? I was trying to avoids hard coding anything into a php ini type file if possible